# RewriteRules opening same page

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have been struggling with this, hope you guys can help me..
I have 2 different rules on this mod_rewrite, however they both open biography_info.php rather than the 2nd one opening char_info.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ biography_info.php?slug=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)-story.html$ char_info.php?slug=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the first one matches the second one too. You could try to switch the order of the rules. Also, I think you must add the L flag too because it must stop at first matching rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)-story.html$ char_info.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ biography_info.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, it will work fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)-story.html$ char_info.php?slug=$1 [QSA, L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).html$ /biography_info.php?slug=$1 [QSA, L]
```